# Dynamic allocation of structure array inside another structure

Tags: arrays, c, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am using WinAPI and am trying create shapes. I have created simple shapes like line,circle and rectangles by creating simple structures.

```
typedef struct _FCOORD{
    float X;
    float Y;
}FCOORD,*PFCOORD;

typedef struct _circledata{
        FCOORD center;
        float radius;
        BOOL filled;
        COLORREF color;
}circle,*circleP;
```

Here FCOORD is structure for storing the coordinates(x,y) as float. Everything is working perfectly.

For Polygon, I have structure to store data of polygon having no. of sides, vertices (x<sub>i</sub> , y<sub>i</sub>). Also the color of the line created by joining (x<sub>i</sub> , y<sub>i</sub>) and (x<sub>i+1</sub> , y<sub>i+1</sub>).

So I have included structure pointer for FCOORD in polydata.

```
typedef struct _polydata{
    int no;
    COLORREF *color;
    PFCOORD points;
}poly,*polyP;
```

Right now I am trying to store just one point(trial phase). So I allocated memory for only one set of data.

```
polyP poy=(polyP)malloc(sizeof(poly));
poy->color=(COLORREF*)malloc(sizeof(COLORREF));
poy->points=(PFCOORD)malloc(sizeof(FCOORD));

//after allocating memory I stored some data

poy->no=5;
poy->color[0]=blue;  // blue is defined as RGB(255,0,0) cause my code works with BGR format for color
poy->points->X=20;
poy->points->Y=20;

//Checking the data
printf("%f %f\n",poy->points->X,poy->points->Y);
printf("%d %d %d\n",poy->color[0],(int)blue);
```

The output is :

```
0 0
255 255
```

blue--> 255 (int value)

The data is correctly set and stored in color[] array but not in structure array points[].
What might have gone wrong in this way of allocating and writing into the memory?
If you can advise another easy way for what I am willing to do, please write codes in simple terms. (I am still a newbie)

Comment: Your `X` and `Y` members are `float` but you are trying to print them with `%d` (i.e. as integers). Use the `%f` format specifier.

Comment: While you're there. the next printf has 3x %d, but only two parameters... strange....

Comment: And you use 'P' to designate a typdef'd pointer type, sometimes it's "Pfoo" and somtimes it's "barP"... Why not be consistent and use 'P' at one end or the other for all tokens?